# jquery to check input in a search and message field

Tags: jquery

I am trying to write jquery code, to check that the message input area has been filled in, before the submit button will send the information. If the field is not filled in then a warning alert box will pop up.  If it has been filled in, then a thank you alert box will pop up.

```
I can get an alert box to work with:  if ($("#search").val() == "") alert ("Empty!");

but I can not get the alert boxes I created to pop up.  Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

        HTML 

      <form id="contact" method="post" action="">
      <!--search for person-->
       <div> 
         <input type="text" id="search" name="search"  placeholder="  Search for          
           User">
       </div>


        <button id="sendButton">SEND</button>

         <div id="sendAlertText">
             <p>Your message has been sent  </p> <p id="sentCross">&#10006;</p>
          </div>

         <div id="emptyAlertText">
             <p>You need to complete all sections before you can send your  
                message</p> <p id="sentCross2">&#10006;
              </p>
             </div>

             </form>


        CSS

        #sendAlertText, #emptyAlertText {
        display: none;
        display:block;
        position:relative;
        margin: 0 20px;
        z-index: 98;
        height: 100px;
        width: 250px;
        background-color: red;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 1.5em;
    }

    #sentCross {
        position: absolute;
        top: -20px;
        right: 2%;
    }

    #emptyAlertText {
        background-color: green;
    }



       JQuery 

       $(document).ready(function() { 

    // MESSAGE INPUT CAN NOT BE BLANK //

    // Hide the alert messages

     $("#sendAlertText").hide();   
     $("#emptyAlertText").hide(); 


     $("#sendButton").click(function() {
        if ($("#search").val() == "") {
            $( "#emptyAlertText" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
        } else {
             $( "#sendAlertText" ).fadeIn( "slow" );
        }


     });
    }
```

Comment: Is the problem that the page is re-loading?

Comment: It could be. Sorry I am a beginner how could I solve the problem if my page is reloading?

Comment: Well, first you need to confirm whether the page *is* reloading.  If it isn't, then that wouldn't be the problem.

Comment: Hello, the page was reloading, thank you.  My else statement is not currently working, so will keep working on this.   Suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an event like the button click not to follow its default behavior, you might want to try the following. In this case, the page will not reload:

```
$("#sendButton").click(function(event) {
    if ($("#search").val() == "") {
        event.preventDefault();
[...]
```

Another hint that just came to my mind is, that you might also consider declaring the button's type attribute. Doing that, the button has no default behaviour anymore:

```
<button id="sendButton" type="button">SEND</button>
```

Comment: Thank you very much